# What is the reason for the name VARGRAPHIC

Tags: db2, history, column-types

I just learned about the DB2 data type VARGRAPHIC and I'm wondering why it has this name? Doesn't seem to be related to graphic in any way.

Comment: I think this should be moved to the DBA site where it should get more attention.

Comment: Not sure about this comment. Developers are the one who write the "create table", and they know what kind of data are dealing with. DBAs care more about database, and not too much about the kind of data stored.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Information Center](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008471.html):

> A *graphic string* is a sequence of bytes that represents double-byte
> character data.

The name may originate from the [RFC on ASCII](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc20), where non-control or alphanumeric characters were referred to as "graphic characters".

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion a Graphic character is not a latin character such as [a-zA-Z] including ñéóíúá, and characters in German, French, etc.

Graphic characters are more about the ones in other languages, such as Mandarin (Chinese), Hebrew, Arab, Japanese, and even characters in Braile. They are very different to any latin character, Hebrew and Arab are written right to left, and Mandarin is up-down, and because of this they are like graphics for the West world (which is based on latin chars.)

Because there are too many characters, they use two bytes (16bits) to represent a single character. With this capacity, they can represent 65535 different characters. (2^16=65535)

A single-byte character is limited to 256 (2^8), and for this reason there are different mappings for this little capacity.